# How to convert html view to a pdf document in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using itextSharp which help me to convert some text to pdf but i want to pass my whole html view via controller and pdf should generate as a report. I am a beginner in MVC 3 so  If any idea than please help.

Comment: @TimPost Just curious why was Preben's answer deleted?